# Not getting the Performance mode on my laptop. Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, performance

I have a Lenovo Legion 5 pro. Which has a Ryzen 7 5800H, Nvidia RTX 3060 and an AMD integrated graphics card. In my laptop, the performance mode is not showing up at all! (it only shows Balanced and Power Saver mode).

My laptop innately has Power saver, Balanced and Performance mode. (The active mode is indicated by a certain color on the power button. It is red for Performance mode). I can see from the color that my laptop is in performance mode, but not really sure if it is actually the case.

```
1. uname -a 
Linux L5Pro-16ACH6H 6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

2. sudo grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/*

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/affected_cpus:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/bios_limit:3200000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpb:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq:1200000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:4462500
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:1200000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_transition_latency:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/freqdomain_cpus:0 1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/related_cpus:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies:3200000 1300000 1200000 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:1200000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:acpi-cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:schedutil
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:3200000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:1200000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed:<unsupported>
grep: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats: Is a directory
```